# How to print only the highest value for a key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I run into a problem when attempting to solve this task so I'm here after failing a few times, I was wondering how could I only print the highest value(score) for a key (name) when a key stores multipile values such as:

```
Rob Scored: 3,5,6,2,8
Martin Scored: 4,3,1,5,6,2
Tom Scored: 7,2,8
```

The name being the key and the scores being the values. Now I wish to get an output of

```
 Martin Scored: 6
 Rob Scored: 8
 Tom Scored: 8
```

However when I attempted the `max` function it would ignore the alphabetical order. Just as a side not that is a requirement as well as the fact that the other scores must be kept stored for later stages.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = {}

for line in f:
    firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')
    dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()
    columns = line.split(": ")
    letters = columns[0]
    numbers = columns[1].strip()
    if d.get(letters):
        d[letters].append(numbers)
    else:
        d[letters] = list(numbers)
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(
sorted((key, list(sorted(vals, reverse=True))) 
       for key, vals in d.items()))
print (sorted_dict)
```

Comment: This question has already been asked today. Strange :D

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: its a txt file and it looks like the first highlighted example of `Rob Scored: ....` rob being the key and the scores being the values

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
# You don't need to use an OrderedDict if you only want to display in
# sorted order once
score_dict = {} # try using a more descriptive variable name

with open('score_file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        name_field, scores = line.split(':') # split the line
        name = name_field.split()[0]         # split the name field and keep 
                                             #     just the name

        # grab all the scores, strip off whitespace, convert to int
        scores = [int(score.strip()) for score in scores.split(',')]

        # store name and scores in dictionary
        score_dict[name] = scores

        # if names can appear multiple times in the input file, 
        # use this instead of your current if statement:
        #
        # score_dict.setdefault(name, []).extend(scores)

# now we sort the dictionary keys alphabetically and print the corresponding
# values
for name in sorted(score_dict.keys()):
    print("{} Scored: {}".format(name, max(score_dict[name])))
```

Please give this document a read: [Code Like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#dictionary-setdefault-method-1). It has a lot of suggestions for how to write better code, and it is where I learned the `dict.setdefault()` method for dealing with dictionaries where the values are lists.

On another note, in your question, you referred to an attempt to use the `max` function, but that function isn't anywhere in the code you provided. If you refer to failed attempts to accomplish something in your question, you should include the failed code as well so we can help you debug it. I was able to give you some code that accomplishes your task along with some other suggestions, but I can't debug your original code if you don't provide it. Since this is obviously a homework question, you should definitely spend some time figuring out why it didn't work in the first place.